# Making directory not accessible Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I made a directory called `downloads` where I will have files that I want people to be able to access with the direct link on my Jekyll site, however I don't want them to be able to go to `https://example.com/downloads` and then see all of the downloads.

How can I turn off visitors from seeing the index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches.

1. You can make an actual `/downloads/index.html` page that will be shown instead of the default directory-like page.
2. You can use the [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) plugin and redirect the url `/downloads/` to your `404` page, for example.